# SQL Rows to Columns sql

Tags: sql-server

```
CallType                Jan   Feb   Mar
vend call Goal >45       0    57    0
OCS call Goal >25        0    13    0
Modified Vend Target     45   38    45
Modified OCS Target      25   25    25
```

I have Table Like this

ButResult I need to show Like This Please Help ...

```
CallType  vend call Goal>45 OCS call Goal>25    ModiVTart    ModifOCSTarget
Jan              0             0                     45              25
Feb              57           13                     38              25
Mar              0             0                     45              25
```

Comment: Please format your question - I'm afraid that nobody is able to understand your problem...

Comment: I am looking at this and I think you just randomly put values here and there. Explain what you have done with tyour table

Comment: So you want to transpose the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE 
(CallType VARCHAR(1000), Jan INT,Feb INT,Mar INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('vend call Goal >45'  ,     0  ,  57  ,  0),
('OCS call Goal >25'   ,     0  ,  13  ,  0),
('Modified Vend Target',     45 ,  38  ,  45),
('Modified OCS Target' ,     25 ,  25  ,  25)
```

### Query

```
SELECT N AS CallType
      ,[vend call Goal >45]
      ,[OCS call Goal >25]
      ,[Modified Vend Target]
      ,[Modified OCS Target]
FROM @TABLE t 
 UNPIVOT (Vals FOR N IN (Jan,Feb,Mar))up
 PIVOT (SUM(Vals)
        FOR CallType
        IN ([vend call Goal >45],[OCS call Goal >25]
            ,[Modified Vend Target],[Modified OCS Target])
        )p
```

### Result Set

```
╔══════════╦════════════════════╦═══════════════════╦══════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ CallType ║ vend call Goal >45 ║ OCS call Goal >25 ║ Modified Vend Target ║ Modified OCS Target ║
╠══════════╬════════════════════╬═══════════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ Feb      ║                 57 ║                13 ║                   38 ║                  25 ║
║ Jan      ║                  0 ║                 0 ║                   45 ║                  25 ║
║ Mar      ║                  0 ║                 0 ║                   45 ║                  25 ║
╚══════════╩════════════════════╩═══════════════════╩══════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```